# If Potential Energy Is only defined For Conservative forces, can Non-conservative forces Increase spring potential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, collision, elasticity

Consider Two Cases Of collision

1. When Energy is conserved before And after collision,we can say That The forces that acted between them were Conservative. During deformation their kinetic converted to potential energy then again all potential Converted to kinetic
2. When Energy Is not conserved before and after collision,so can we define any potential energy transfers here?If not how can we say that during deformation,some kinetic converted to potential??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are misusing the term [conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force). A conservative force is one which depends only on the position of an object, and not on its velocity, acceleration, orientation etc. For example, potential energy is defined for a spring because the force exerted by the spring depends only on the distance by which it is compressed or extended, and not on how fast it has been compressed etc.

Secondly energy is always conserved as long as we take into account all of the places that energy can be. When we informally talk about energy being “lost” e.g. in an inelastic collision we mean that some energy has been dissipated into the environment as heat or sound waves.

But if I take your question to mean

> In an inelastic collision is some kinetic energy converted into potential energy of the spring ?

then the answer is yes. But not *all* of the kinetic energy of the colliding object is converted into potential energy.